# Java: Create random sequence of values from 0 to x (no repeat, all present)

Tags: java, random

Is there a way to create a random sequence of numbers from 0 to x (Exclusive) such that

1. All numbers are in the sequence
2. There are no repeats

For example, for 0 to 5, possible values are:
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 0, 2, 1]

It is okay if they are in an array, I just need to process them randomly.

Comment: Yes, there is..

Comment: int[] randomSequence = new Random().ints(0, 5).distinct().limit(5).toArray();

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of integer which you can shuffle using Collections.shuffle(myList). (you need to import: "import java.util.Collections;" at the top of your document.

Comment: Oh and it may require you to also import "import java.util.ArrayList;" and "import java.util.List;" if it doesn't work, like it did with me just now when i tried it.